# Sencha touch will not build using Cordova

Tags: java, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I created a project using Sencha Touch, that I wanted to convert to a hybrid app.

I ran the `sencha cordova init <APP_ID> <APP_NAME>` with success, as it created the folder structure.

But the problem comes, when I run `sencha app build -run native` (of course I have set it to run to a specific platform).

I then tried another thing, went to `<project-folder>/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/` and ran `build.bat`, but it came with 7 errors and 3 warnings, where I can guess, that the main error is the cause. It says `package org.apache.cordova does not exist`, but how can I fix that?

I have set up Ant, Cordova, Java SDK and so on.

So I think it is a problem with Android and Cordova?

Comment: you don't need cordova and phonegap, they can mess with each other. uninstall cordova if you are planning to use phonegap.

Comment: try running `sencha app -d build native` first (without `run` and with `-d` which is debug) this should give you more detail about the error you have

Comment: `sencha app -d build native` says that `d` is not a property

Comment: haha, sorry `sencha -d app build native` :)

Comment: Again it says the same that `package org.apache.cordova does not exist` :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason, why it could not build

The path for the `<project-folder>` was `c:\Users\<my-name>\bin\<project-name>`, but it can not have `bin` in the path for the `<project-folder>` as it is replaced by a build-script.